# Emulate C datatypes in C#

Tags: c#, c, types, int, teamspeak

Is there a way to emulate special C datatypes, like uint64 (_int64), anyID (_int16) in C#?
I defined the special datatypes in C like this:

```
typedef unsigned _int16 anyID;
typedef unsigned _int64 uint64;
```

Its for using the TS3 Plugin API.
It has to be C# though, and I just want to use the from TS3 defined C datatypes in C#.

Comment: `using anyID = Int16;`

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of a typedef is `using`:

```
using anyID = System.UInt16;
using uint64 = System.UInt64;
```

The sizes of the different numeric types in C# can be found here: [Integral Types Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx).

One thing to note: the sizes of the different numeric types are fixed in C#, unlike in C where they are platform-dependent, so it's usually redundant to define aliases for numeric type sizes like `int64`.

Comment: Interesting that while `ushort` is normally equivalent to `System.UInt16`, for the `using` it isn't...

Comment: Yup, that got me at first, too.

Answer (score 0):

unsigned ints are already predefined See [MS c# types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx)

in short: ushort is an unsigned 16bit int, and ulong is an unsigned 64bit int..

Comment: And how can I declare an alias? So like, when I write uint64 it takes it as ulong?

Comment: Use a using statement such as using _int16 = ushort;

Comment: Turns out ushort is an alias anyway, so you can do "using _int16= System.UInt16;"

Answer (score 0):

For unsigned integers you have `ushort`, `uint` and `ulong`, which is the equivalent to `unsigned int16`, `unsigned int32` and `unsigned int64` respectively.